# Static placeholder for input

Tags: html, css

I don't know what will be the correct title for this question. I have inputbox with 'static placeholder', example for url [jsfiddle.net/manyahin/MxRqX](http://jsfiddle.net/manyahin/MxRqX)

```
<div class="controls">
 <input type="text" />
 <span>http://</span>
</div>
```

User can't delete http:// and type text after this. Span have margin-left: minus for position above input, and input have text-ident for get free space for span.

When I click at input, cursor set in start of input, before http. And when I start typing, cursor go to normal position. How to fix this bug or please give me an alternative method to make this happen. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you post a working version of what you'd like to achieve/fix at http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we may work on it?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be doing whatever you are trying to do here, but if you wish to tell the user that he should enter a URL without http:// prefix (which will be implied), then you can use just `http://<input type="text">`. Alternatively, and better, use just <input type="url">. More often than not, people will copy and paste a URL (and should do so), so trying to make them omit `http://` is a nuisance, not convenience to them.

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/manyahin/MxRqX/

Answer (score 1):

If the input text always needs to start with http:// the easier way would be to put it as a label before the field rather than in it and then prepend the http:// on the backend.   or you could catch it on the back end and read the text from the input field and prepend http:// to the input text if the user didn't enter this.

another way would be through jquery where you can set the value of the text box to be http:// with whatever text the user inputs.

A third less elegant way is to use two input fields and use css to position and style them to appear as one.  set the first field value to http:// (assuming it is always going to be http://) and set it to readonly.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `:before` in css?

Give this a go....
http://jsfiddle.net/MxRqX/3/

Comment: I'm looking for an answer like yours, however the example you provided doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use pseudo-elements such as :before and :after on elements like input. The content render needs to be inside a container, and the input is not a container.

Comment: However, you could put it on the placeholder :) like this: input::-webkit-input-placeholder:before. Do not forget to use all "moz, ms, webkit" prefixes for a crossbrowser solution.